# Using Printer with Stream

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am migrating from Richfaces to Primefaces. In my existing application, i have a print use case where when a user clicks the print button the Printer bean writes the pdf(along with print Javascript) content to outputstream and on client side print dialog containing the pdf content is opened automatically. With Richfaces i have used the following snippet:

```
<a4j:mediaOutput element="object" type="application/pdf" mimeType="application/pdf"
            createContent="#{printerBean.generatePrintOutput}" value="#{dataBean.printObject}"
            style="width: 0px; height: 0px;" cacheable="false"
            classid="CLSID:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000"/>
```

The above works fine with richfaces and i want to achieve the same with primefaces but could not find an exact alternative. The **createContent** attribute above does the magic .i.e. pass the outputstream and printObject to my printerBean.generatePrintOutput method. Please help me how can i achieve this with primefaces.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code sample:

**The View**

```
<h:form id="mainForm">

    <p:commandButton value="Generate" action="#{mediaBean.generatePrintOutput}" update="read" />

    <p:outputPanel id="read">
        <p:media value="#{mediaBean.media}" width="100%" height="590"
                 player="pdf" rendered="#{not empty mediaBean.media}" />
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

**MediaBean**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MediaBean {

    private byte[] data;

    public void generatePrintOutput() throws IOException {
        //simulates the genration of the pdf
        data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("D:/cars.pdf"));
    }

    public StreamedContent getMedia() throws IOException {
        if (data == null) {
            return null;
        }
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        StreamedContent pdf = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf");
        return pdf;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to update the **D:/cars.pdf** to target a pdf in your own file system.

Comment: This sample downloads the pdf, how can i just write to output stream with special headers for download?

Comment: The sample only downloads if you browser doesn't support pdf display. I've tested it in Chrome and the pdf is displayed as part of the page right after the button. Anyway, I've updated the answer to be less confusing.

Comment: Now if you include a button with a `<p:printer>` tag, I can delete my answer. Also, take a look at the [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/media.jsf) to display an alternative text when no pdf player can be found.

Comment: My original answer had that text for no pdf player found, but I delete it after @user3027786 comment ;)

Comment: I tried the above, it works for Chrome and Firefox but IE version 8 i don't see any content. Only gray area no other clue :( There is no exception on server side. What could be the reason??? Further, i observed that PDF player does caching. First time it sends request to server and later no request is sent. How can i avoid this caching?